# Coinbase accepting BTC - pre-populate an amount for iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, bitcoin, coinbase-api

Is there a way of showing a Coinbase iframe with an amount pre-populated (instead of allowing the user to change the amount in the iframe)? Ideally I'd like the ability for the user to enter in an amount before he/she clicks on a 'pay with bitcoin' button.

I know this can probably done by calling the API to regenerate a new iframe when the user clicks a button but I'd rather not do that each time a button is clicked.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you'd like to create payment buttons or iFrames with a static amount, it's typically easiest to just create a new one for each transaction.  If you'll only be using each iFrame once, you can create a new one with just one API endpoint:
https://developers.coinbase.com/api#create-an-order-for-a-button

I'd recommend also taking a look at the Coinbase client libraries (https://developers.coinbase.com/api#api-client-libraries); they can greatly simplify the integration process.  The API support team can also be reached at api@coinbase.com.

Hope that helps; happy to answer any additional questions that come up.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using Stripe's API in the end which allowed me to pass in an amount without having to request a new bit of HTML each time.